# ASP.net and Windows Forms - Send an Application, Execute it and then Delete it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.net (VB) application and an EXE (VB.net). I need that my ASP application send the EXE to the cliente, targeting the "%Temp%" folder, then the software be executed and when it ends, be deleted.

Both softwares, the ASP.net (that runs on a server in my network) and the EXE were written by me; all works.

Problem on ASP.net : It sends the download, the browser shows the windows to the user to choose the folder he wishes to save the EXE. I'd like to SUGGEST (because I know that I can't force him to save on a specific folder) the "%Temp%" folder.

Problem on EXE : It executes (at user's double click) and do all the tasks with perfection. I need that, when it ends, it erases it self from the HD. I've seen programs executing copies of then selfs directly from memory, then my EXE could do that, on the first call it copies itself to the memory and executes from there, leaving the file on disc free to be deleted after the process is completed.

I have this question on MSDN already (in Portuguese, my native language) on this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/0596361e-5609-447a-8c78-e3d4db138c26/aspnet-e-windows-form-enviar-um-aplicativo-executlo-e-depois-exclulo?forum=vsvbasicpt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing following trick to delete exe file after execution; code is C# though, but you should get the idea. Execute this right before your app exits:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath);

var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 5 & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(info);

Application.Exit();
```

It executes shell delete command five seconds +- after application exits.

Comment: Ondrej, thank you - i'll test it right away, but i beleave it's the proper way to do what i want.

I'll keep the question open a little longer to see if anyone anwser the ASP.net part of my question - if not, i'll mark your answer as the answer to my question and close it, because from both questions, this one was what i needed the most.